# Xamarin read from wifi send via cellular

Tags: xamarin, wifi, cellular-network

I am relatively new to Xamarin but have a project that needs me to read packets from a wifi connection and then send the data to an endpoint via the phones Mobile/cellular connections.

Can this be done as I am struggling with this one.

Cliff.

Comment: You generally don't have control over the interface that is used to send traffic.  The OS handles this for you.

Comment: Thats the thing I need to basically read data from a sensor over wifi and stream it to a server via the 4G connection live. I am hoping to use a phone as it is built and works I just need to write and app, otherwise I need to start playing with hardware which will take longer.

Comment: Have you seen any apps that do this?  Generally if your phone is connected to a local WiFi without internet access then you can only access that local WiFi, even if you still have a data connection via your carrier

Comment: I would agree with @Jason here as this is a thing the OS handles. You could try setting the default network(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#setProcessDefaultNetwork(android.net.Network) / https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#bindProcessToNetwork(android.net.Network)) Android 5.0 can potentially help here with the `OnAvailable()` callback and checking the respective `Network` object - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Wireless

Comment: @CliffordAgius I worked on a marine sensor system and what we did to reduce hardware development costs was to use two Android devices. (Wifi Sensor network) -> (Wifi) -> Droid1 -> (BlueTooth) -> Droid2 -> (Celluar) -> Collection Server. The assumption was that custom Android hardware would be created later, the system worked great and the hardware cost of two low end phones vs. custom hardware in low qty (# of collection nodes was ~100), the multi-phone deployment won by a cost saving factor of 10x plus we could add satellite-modems to the mix when needed

Comment: @SushiHangover that is a perfect solution and I hope you don't mind but I'm going to borrow it.

Comment: @Jason yes all mobile can share thier data via a wifihotspot I just need my device to connect to a wifi hotspot and share the data it recieves over it's data connection.

Comment: @CliffordAgius yes, but mobile hotspots are implemented by the OS/Carrier and don't typically provide APIs to app developers.  You could also look at IoT Systems that are more open

Comment: @CliffordAgius No problem ;-) Good luck on your project